# i was working on a discord bot and i needed a money system .unfortunately every time i run the code it gave me the key error

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord.py, bots

Mostly I just want the bot to update and display the account of users. I do not understand JSON python very well so that might be a stupid question but I hope I can fix it. If you need more detail plz tell me. I am using python 3.7.0. The JSON file is empty  (It just has two curly brackets).
But if you wonder, here is how it looks

```
{


}
```

````
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import os

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Vrishnee\\Desktop\\Project for server")

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "-" )


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("I have been awoken")


@client.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    uses = await get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]

    em = discord.embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance", color = discord.Color.red())
    em.add_field(name = "Wallet", value = wallet_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)
    
@client.command()
async def beg(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    users = await get_bank_data()
    user = ctx.author

    earnings = random.randrange(101)

    await ctx.send(f"Someone give you {earnings} coin")

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] + earnings

    with open ("MoneyBank.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)

    

async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users [str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0

    with open ("MoneyBank.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
    return true

async def get_bank_data():
    with open ("MoneyBank.json","r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    return users



client.run("persoal info sorry")```

I'm not good at debugging so yes.

```Ignoring exception in command balance:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vrishnee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Vrishnee\Desktop\Project for server\AnArchversalBot.py", line 18, in balance
    await open_account(ctx.author)
  File "C:\Users\Vrishnee\Desktop\Project for server\AnArchversalBot.py", line 52, in open_account
    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
KeyError: '694079286960848957'
````

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vrishnee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Vrishnee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Vrishnee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: '694079286960848957'
```

Comment: You're trying to get a value from an empty dictionary, it's obvious it's gonna throw `KeyError`. What else were you expecting?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński make sense now that you have said it but what should i write in my json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can use .txt files to save accounts informations...
Like this:

```
@client.command()
async def show_profile(ctx):
   with open(f"{ctx.author.id}'s Account.txt", "r") as doc:
      money = doc.read()
   
   await ctx.send(f"Here's you're money: {money}")
```

If you want to update the money:

```
@client.command()
async def add_money(ctx, user:discord.Member, money):
   with open(f"{user.id}'s Account.txt","r") as doc_r:
      old_money = doc_r.read()

   with open(f"{user.id}'s Account.txt","w") as doc_w:
      new_money = int(old_money) + int(money)
      doc_w.write(new_money)
   
   await ctx.send("Money updated!")
```

If you want to save multiple informations in a single .txt file, you can use the `.readlines` function. Like this:

```
@client.command()
async def show_profile(ctx):
   with open(f"{ctx.author.id}'s Account","r") as doc:
      lines = doc.readlines()
      
      money = lines[0] #here you obtain the 1st line
      other_things = lines[1] #here you obtain the 2nd line

      money = money.replace(r"\n","") #note that you have to remove the \n
      other_things = other_things.replace(r"\n","")

      await ctx.send(f"Here's you're money: {money}\nAnd the other things: {other_things}")
```

EDIT:

With the function `open()`, you can write and read files.
If you want to read:

```
with open("FileName","r") as document:
   content = document.read()
```

Note that, next to the filename, there's an `r`, here, you can insert `r`, `w` and `a`.
With `r`, you can use read functions like `.readlines()`, `.read()`, `.readline()`.
With the `w`, you can write something into the file, BUT, if you use `w`, all the informations that there were before, will be deleted, instead if you use `a`, you can write informations below the others.

If you want more details, I thing you can understand better [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/file-operation).

Yes I know that my english is terrible but those are details.

Comment: how to create a file if there is no file for the user. Sorry I am very new to this domain

Comment: If working with JSON files wasn't bad enough... TXT files are even worse.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński yea but here at least i got an expert to talk about problem

Comment: i got an index error. Index out of ranges.